# Coded UI resume existing recording

Tags: coded-ui-tests

In Visual Studi you can do recording in IE as an example. You enter an url, insert some data and finish your recording. After that some code are generated. What if you want to change the recording? How do you resume a recording if something in the user interface changes? Do you have to sart all over start a recording based on the generated code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add new recordings without losing the old. The normal recorder is used. When you save a part of the recording you name the action or assertion method. If the same name as an existing method is used than that method is replaced. However a completely new method can be created.

**Assuming that you are using the default UT Map** then position the cursor in the c where the new method should be called. Use the context (right-click) menu at that cursor position (I find adding a empty line makes it obvious where the new call will be inserted) and select the command **Generate code for Coded UI test** => **Use Coded UI test builder**. The normal Coded UI recorder will start.

**If you are using multiple UI Maps** then select the UI Map to have the new code and from its context menu select the ""Edit with Coded UI test builder" command. After recording a new method, add a call of it in the required test method.

---

If the new recording is wanted to replace a small part of an existing method, or to go in the middle, then I recommend using the UI Map editor to split the existing method into two or more pieces and then use the recorder to replace the unwanted part leaving the wanted parts as originally recorded.

---

A breakpoint can be set within a Coded UI test then, when the test is run in debug mode, execution will stop at the breakpoint. This lets the test be executed as so as to move the application being tested to a specific place within the test. Having reached the desired breakpoint, the test execution (ie the debug session) should be stopped. At this time the application is waiting for further input and the recording actions described above can be used. There are several ways of startng the test in debug mode, including the options on the "Run test" icon and the context menu of the `[TestMethod]`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Adrian. What I am looking for is more running an exitsting recording again until you at a curtain point. Lets say you navigate through 4 pages and end out filling a form. But a new textbox has been added to the form. Whats the proccess for running the recording again until you reach the form, and then add text to the new textbox?

Comment: Just tested it and your completely right. If you stop the debugger in a debugging session it dosent close the browser and you can start a new recording session. Thanks!